# Prestashop - No payment method in checkout page

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I need your help to solve an annoying problem I'm having on a website with PrestaShop 1.7.

When I'm in the checkout page, after filling in the billing/shipping address, I must choose the carrier, and here comes the problem: I have 3 different carriers, but when it comes to pick up the payment method, they always says "Unfortunately, there is no payment method available" except one that shows it correctly (see screenshot attached).

[Checkout - payment methods](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjYNl.png)

I have checked the payment method settings in the back-office and, where I should assign the each payment method to a specific carrier, I see that it doesn't work as expected, since all of them are unselectable, except for one that isn't even the same that works correctly during the checkout procedure. For the records, the only one that is editable, doesn't work (see the other screenshot).

[Back-office - Payment carrier restrictions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpyxb.png)

Am I missing something? Is there a bug or an incompatibility between payment methods? Does anyone encurred in a similar problem?

Thank you in advance!

P.S.: sorry for the second screenshot in italian, I have translated it next to each term.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Everyone here is a workaround
1.- Find the table prefix_carrier -> take note of the field id_reference of all your active carriers
2.- Find the tables prefix_module -> take note of the field id_module of all your active payment module
3.- Find the table prefix_module_carrier -> you will see that there are missing entries for your carrier id_reference with the payment id_module associated, create the missing one
the row id_module is the id of the payment module that you have active
the row id_reference is the id of the carrier that you want thar payment to be available.
Still do not know what is causing these records to disappear but this solves the issue, have a good day :)

Answer (score 0):

i have found another workaround as i had the same issue.
It seems, that there is a problem with carrier restrictions under payment preferences, where somehow it doesn't show full data.
What I did to fix the issue :

1. Open your carrier list (under shipping / carriers);
2. Find the carrier you want to fix ;
3. Change its name (i just added "1" in the end of it) ;
4. Go back to payments -> preferences -> carrier restrictions. You should see a new carrier which has the name you updated without any checked payment methods (the one with "1" at the end in my case) ;
5. Check all the necessary payment methods ;
6. Go back to carrier list and restore the name of it (in my case i have deleted "1" at the end) ;

i hope it helps for someone :)

Answer (score 0):

I confirm I could see missing entries in the _module_carrier db table, to enable the carrier/payment method match (see Austral answer).
To solve **I just reinstalled the payment module** (Paypal in my case), that created the missing matches, without editing anything manually in the database.